# unwanted border on image css styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script id="canteen_card_row_template" type="text/html">
        <div class="normal-box">
                        <div class="subtitle-box">
                            <div class="mensa-img">
                                <img src="{{type.[0].image}}" id="mensa-image">
                            </div><span class="options-title" id="mensa-text">{{title.de_DE}}</span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="side-text-box">
                            <span class="side-text">{{price.student}}€</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-text">
                            <span class="normal-text" id="mensa-text">{{content}}</span>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

CSS

```
#mensa-image{
height: 13px;
width:13px;
border: none !important;}
```

I have the problem where `img src="blabla"` is... Using handlebars and a webservice that template is loaded 4 times.. The fourth `"normal-box"` does not have content therefore no image(thats ok).. the problem is, since it has no image the `div` where the image is placed should be blank, but there an unwanted border instead... Here is an image of how it looks like [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp7hj.png)

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle or link to a live example?

Comment: Its browser default value when img is not found. One way to fix it is to use .png photo with transparent background on it(you need to do empty .png image and it to "blabla")

Answer (score 3):

Use 0 instead of none

```
border: 0;
```

not

```
border: none;
```

Also, if you are generating multiple "mensa-image" images then you should be using class instead of ID.

Comment: deleted the id and added 0 instead of none, but the border is still there :/

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki create a live example.so it is easy to edit and test the solution

Comment: Replace the ID with.... class="mensa-image".  Then in your CSS .mensa-image { border:0; }

Comment: @Fast Snail +1... create a jsfiddle

Comment: I fixed it. Added an {{#if type.[0].image}} <img src="...."> {{/if}} because I found out chrome assignes a border to images without src... so if the webservice delivers no image it simply leaves the div blank

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS rule instead and remove the ID from the image:

```
.mensa-image img {
  border: none;
}
```

and HTML (partly):

```
<div class="subtitle-box">
  <div class="mensa-img">
    <img src="{{type.[0].image}}">
  </div>
  <span class="options-title">{{title.de_DE}}</span>
</div>
```

As @Lowcase wrote, you should not use an ID several times (same for the text `span`, BTW). If you simply remove the ID, the above rule should work.

Comment: please note my edited answer (edited several times - sorry for the confusion)

Answer (score 1):

That's the work of the browser when no image is found. The easiest fix is just to add a transparent .png.

Comment: The only answer that actually addresses the cause of the problem